# How to get the coordinates of the upper and lower part from a line in a grid using python?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to get the coordinates of boxes above and below the line in a grid of shape N*N.
I was wondering how to get the coordinates?

Of course for small N, I can simply look at the boxes and say it has these coordinates but for large N, its impossible to eyeballing and getting the coordinates.

Problem setup:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)


plt.plot((2,9),(0,8))
plt.xticks(x)
plt.yticks(y)
```

[image]

For example, in this case, we have N = 10.
I would like to get the coordinates above and below the red line.
for example, the Required answer should have the following points:

```
above the line:
[(0,0), (1,0), (2,1), ... , (8,9)]

Below line:
[ (2,0), (3,0), (3,1), (4,0), (4,1), ... , (8,6)]

Note: as I have shown if the line touches the box is considered to bottom part.
      For example, box (2,0) is below the line.
```

## Update @Quang Hong

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)

pt1, pt2 = (2,0), (9,8)

# sort
pt1, pt2 = sorted([pt1, pt2])

# this is the function
def func(x,y):
    return  (y-pt1[1]) * (pt2[0] - pt1[0]) - (x - pt1[0]) * (pt2[1] - pt1[1]) 



vals = func(x[None,:], y[:, None])

aboves = np.where(vals > 0)
belows = np.where(vals < 0)

plt.plot(aboves[0], aboves[1],'ro')
plt.plot(belows[0], belows[1],'bo')
plt.xticks(x)
plt.yticks(y)
```

[image]

Comment: How (in what format) do we get the line? I assume it's just a straight line?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The red line is a straight line between two points in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little math, you can create a function which is `>0` for points above the line:

```
pt1, pt2 = (2,0), (9,8)

# sort
pt1, pt2 = sorted([pt1, pt2])

# this is the function
def func(x,y):
    return  (y-pt1[1]) * (pt2[0] - pt1[0]) - (x - pt1[0]) * (pt2[1] - pt1[1]) 



vals = func(x[:, None], y[None, :])

aboves = np.where(vals > 0)
belows = np.where(vals < 0)

plt.scatter(aboves[0], aboves[1])
plt.scatter(belows[0], belows[1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hoang, Thanks a lot, but when I use x=np.arange(10) the plot looks different for me. Let me show reflection on the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves the problem. (probably I need to add two orange points at (2,0) and (9,0) but that's a minor addition.

Comment: @MilkyWay001 You could replace `belows = np.where(vals < 0)` by `belows = np.where(vals <= 0)`

Comment: @JohanC that includes points **on** the lines. Depending on what OP wants.